# Unable to find a specification for `PrivatePodBB` depended upon by `PrivatePodAA`

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have created 2 private pods first one is PrivatePodAA and second one is PrivatePodBB , I can successfully use PrivatePodBB in PrivatePodAA podfile but while trying to add it as dependency in PrivatePodAA podspec file and trying to install PrivatePodAA as a pod in new project it's showing :

```
Unable to find a specification for `PrivatePodBB` depended upon by `PrivatePodAA`
```

I have created my own private repo and added PrivatePodBB podspec file in it.

Below my podfile for `PrivatePodAA` which is working perfectly :

```
// my private repo url
source 'https://privateurl.prv/scm/ios/sdhub.git'
target 'PrivatePodAA' do
    pod 'PrivatePodBB', :git => 'https://privateurl.prv/scm/ios/PrivatePodBB.git'
    # pod 'PrivatePodBB' # this also working fine
end
```

And below podspec file for `PrivatePodAA` which which causing the problem :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'PrivatePodAA'
  s.source           = {
     :git => 'https://privateurl.prv/scm/ios/PrivatePodAA.git', :tag => s.version.to_s
  }
  s.dependency 'PrivatePodBB'
end
```

Also while running : `pod spec lint --sources=my-private-repo,master`
working perfectly

So, please what is missed from the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I have finally reached to that adding the source for my private repo to my new project solving my problem .. Below sample podfile for my new project :

```
source 'https://privateurl.prv/scm/ios/sdhub.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'testPrivatePod' do
  # Pods for testPrivatePod
  pod 'PrivatePodAA', :git => 'https://privateurl.prv/scm/ios/PrivatePodAA.git', :branch => 'privatePods'
end
```